# Programmatically changing file icons in Visual Studio 2005's solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm writing an add-in for Visual Studio, which must be compatible with VS 2005. This add-in involves marking certain files as "special", and I'd really like to make their specialness visually apparent in the Solution Explorer - currently my users either have to manually keep a note of which files are special, or right-click on each potentially special file and see what menu items are there.

Ideally I'd like to change the icon, but I'd be happy to (for instance) make the file's name bold or something.

Unfortunately, all the appearance-related methods seem to live on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.FileNode, and I only have access to UIHierarchyItems and ProjectItems. I've spent several days grovelling through MSDN, and I can't find any way of constructing a FileNode given a ProjectItem or UIHierarchyItem. There's a suggested solution on the MSDN forums, but it assumes you're starting with a FileNode, and as far as I can tell this implies creating a custom project type (and presumably some sort of project-conversion system). I don't think my users would be too happy with this.

Or is there something I'm missing?